# Extract data from FirebaseListObservable to Array

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

sorry for my english, i have this observable:

```
this.productos = af.database.list('/productos', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'categoria',
      equalTo: this.catnombre
    }
    });
```

I need extract all id from here and set in a array but i dont know how, thanks.

Edit:

I can extract the id but I use de key, now i need extract other data, but snapshot.val, dont work.

```
  this.productos = af.database.list('/productos/', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'categoria',
      equalTo: this.catnombre
    }, preserveSnapshot:true
    });

    this.productos.subscribe(snapshot => {

         snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {

           console.log(snapshot.key);
           this.idproductos.push(snapshot.key); 

         });
         console.log(this.idproductos);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
this.productos = af.database.list('/productos/', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'categoria',
      equalTo: this.catnombre
    })
  .map(products => products.map(product => product.$key));
```

The result will be an observable of arrays of keys. Now you can subscribe it to or do whatever else you want to.

```
this.productos.subscribe(keys => console.log("keys are", keys));
```

If AngularFire, and things like `FirebaseListObservable`, are used correctly, you don't need to worry about snapshots, or taking their `val()`, or doing `forEach` on them, or taking elements and putting them onto your own array. The `FirebaseListObservable` is an observable of arrays. Simply `map` it to create other observables, as we have done above to create an observable of arrays of keys, or subscribe to it to get the underlying data.

Comment: The problem is that i need this array for others fnctions, i dont know how read a observable.

Comment: i suggest reading, or re-reading, a good tutorial on observables. You "read an observable" by subscribing to it, and then doing things you want to do with the data in the handler you pass to `subscribe`. One thing you can do in the subscribe handler is store a copy of the data somewhere, which is fine, as long as you remember that the data won't be available until the observable starts firing--in the case of AngularFire, until the data has been retrieved.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, i will try, thamks you very much.